# How to make Webpack use project's "node_modules" in js scripts located outside the project folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have Node.js project and the following structure of folders:

- lib

  - awesome-formatter.js
- FrontEndApp

  - prettify.js
  - node_modules

    - awesome-parser
- BackEndApp

  - ...

I use `awesome-parser` module and `awesome-formatter.js` library in `prettify.js` script like this:

```
require('awesome-parser')

require('../lib/awesome-formatter.js')
```

`awesome-formatter.js`, in turns, should use `awesome-parser` too:

```
require('awesome-parser')
```

My `FrontEndApp` has been configured to use Webpack, and I'm trying to run it in dev mode using `npm run dev` command. However, I got the following error:

> ERROR Failed to compile with 1 errors
>
> These dependencies were not found:
>
> * awesome-parser in /home/user/dev/lib/awesome-formatter.js

I don't want to move `awesome-formatter.js` inside the `FrontEndApp` because I also use it in `BackEndApp` project (and probably in some other projects) and I don't want to create separate "node_modules" in "lib" for it just not to duplicate installed modules on disk.

So, my question is, how to make Webpack use project's "node_modules" in js scripts located outside the project folder?

P.S. Of course there are workarounds like symlinks or making  a full-featured module (with package.json etc.) from `lib/awesome-fromatter` and installing it into `FrontEndApp/node_modules`, but is there a direct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution: `resolve.modules` sould be added to Webpack configuration file.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
  ...
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      resolve('node_modules')
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

This means that Webpack is searching modules in 'node_modules' as a relative subfolder (and it's the usual behavior), and at the absolute path to the project's 'node_modules' as well: `resolve('node_modules')`, so that scripts in folders outside the project (like `lib` in my structure) can find and use it.

Comment: `resolve('node_modules')` should be `path.resolve('node_modules')` ?